# Is it possible to make a declarative sentence starting with 'Can'?

Tags: questions, sentence-patterns, question-mark, imperatives

everyone
As the title shows, is it possible to make a declarative sentence starting with "Can"?
For example, **'Please, can we request that you do not accept any proposals from him.'**
The reason why I ask this question is that I saw the example sentence, which is written in an official document made by a British writer. As you see, there is no question mark (?) at the end of the sentence, so I thought it was a typo at first glance. But it was not.

Comment: "Can you be any stupider?" is declarative in effect (think Chandler Bing, if you can). It's certainly not asking for an answer. Maybe you should consider what you mean by "declarative".

Answer (score 3):

Your example sentence is more nearly imperative than declarative, but whatever terminology you apply to it, it isn't a normal interrogative form, and—at least according to *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010)—it doesn't have to end in a question mark:

> **6.69 *Requests as questions.*** A request disguised s a question does not require a question mark. Such formulations can usually be reduced to the imperative.
>
> > Would you kindly respond by March 1.
> >
> > *or*
> >
> > Please respond by March 1.

If I recall correctly, an earlier edition of *Chicago* provided as an example the evocative expression, "Will the congregation please rise." Evidently, the speaker in that case has no doubt that they will.

Comment: *But if we ask a favor or make a request that the reader may be unable or unwilling to grant, we use a question mark. This allows the reader the chance to say no.*

Comment: @Sandip Kumar Mandal
 Yes, I'd say the question mark is optional in these polite requests, and as you say its inclusion is more geared to a refusal.

Answer (score 3):

Of course we can do so:

> "Can" is a modal auxiliary verb.
> Can pigs fly is a question that puzzles me.

However, you are probably interested in situations in which "can" is not used *qua* a word, in quoted text, within a subordinate clause, etc. In that case, there is only one situation that I know of in which the verb "can" can appear as the first word of a declarative clause, and that is with exclamatory expressions. For example:

> "Can she swim?"
> "**Can** she ever!"

(Note that I would say that your example sentence includes a clause of the interrogative type despite lacking a question mark. Terminology often varies.)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, if the subject is after "can"  it's a question and should end with a question mark.

> Can you use the phone?
> If the subject is before "can" then it's not a question and is a statement most of the time. It should therefore end with a full stop or an exclamation mark.
> You can use the phone.

There are loopholes which will allow you to get around this general rule such as quoting Can instead of actually using it, as mentioned in another answer:

> Can pigs fly is a question that puzzles me.

But I don't think this would count as a correct answer.

And of course you could use "can" as an object and you can easily put that into a declarative sentence:

> Can-throwing is not allowed in the building